# Python RSS Feed Not Updating

Tags: bug, rss

The [Python RSS feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/python) has seemingly not updated in almost two days. Given the historical frequency of new Python questions I find this difficult to believe. My other Stack Overflow feeds have been updating.

Comment: Can't reproduce; the first post in the feed right now is [this one from 9 mins ago](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43262177).

Comment: And testing almost 5 minutes later, I see new entries, like [First Value in Pandas DatetimeIndex is Unsearchable](//stackoverflow.com/q/43261760) (updated just 2 minutes ago as an answer was edited).

Comment: The error appears to be only reproducible for me when using a TLS connection; an unsecured HTTP connection does not exhibit the error.

Comment: My tests were all over HTTPS.

Comment: When I attempt to validate the feed using Thunderbird, I get a warning I don't see on my other feeds: "[Self reference doesn't match document location](https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/warning/SelfDoesntMatchLocation.html)". What other information can I give you to aid in error reproduction?

Comment: Could you try to reproduce this with `curl`? Just grep for the `http://stackoverflow.com/q/` lines in the output, or the `<updated>` timestamps, to see if they are recent. Please also do try this on a different network to rule out a local issue.

Comment: The other feed I am comparing it against is the [PHP feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/php).

Comment: The feedvalidator's only problem with the current feed is that there's a namespace it doesn't recognise: https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Ffeeds%2Ftag%2Fpython

Comment: That now appears to be case. I'll check the feed with curl in a minute.

Comment: Note that the feed is compressed; `curl -s https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/python | gunzip -c | grep '<updated>'` works for me to decompress and list only the updated timestamps (the PHP feed is not compressed, interestingly enough, I guess it is adaptive).

Comment: First update: 2017-04-05T01:48:44Z, Last update: 2017-04-05T02:31:41Z

Comment: That's... very different from my response: https://pastebin.com/jhLTpDHn

Comment: Agreed: https://pastebin.com/htY1vUpe

Answer (score 11):

For me it looks like the *unencrypted version* is out of sync, on all 4 IP addresses advertised to me:

```
$ host stackoverflow.com
stackoverflow.com has address 151.101.1.69
stackoverflow.com has address 151.101.65.69
stackoverflow.com has address 151.101.193.69
stackoverflow.com has address 151.101.129.69
stackoverflow.com mail is handled by 10 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
stackoverflow.com mail is handled by 10 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
stackoverflow.com mail is handled by 1 aspmx.l.google.com.
stackoverflow.com mail is handled by 5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
stackoverflow.com mail is handled by 5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
mjpieters@mjpieters-mbp:~ $ curl -s -H "Host: stackoverflow.com" http://151.101.1.69/feeds/tag/python  | gunzip -c | grep '<updated>' | head -n1
    <updated>2017-04-04T11:18:14Z</updated>
mjpieters@mjpieters-mbp:~ $ curl -s -H "Host: stackoverflow.com" http://151.101.65.69/feeds/tag/python  | gunzip -c | grep '<updated>' | head -n1
    <updated>2017-04-04T11:18:14Z</updated>
mjpieters@mjpieters-mbp:~ $ curl -s -H "Host: stackoverflow.com" http://151.101.193.69/feeds/tag/python  | gunzip -c | grep '<updated>' | head -n1
    <updated>2017-04-04T11:18:14Z</updated>
mjpieters@mjpieters-mbp:~ $ curl -s -H "Host: stackoverflow.com" http://151.101.129.69/feeds/tag/python  | gunzip -c | grep '<updated>' | head -n1
    <updated>2017-04-04T11:18:14Z</updated>
mjpieters@mjpieters-mbp:~ $ curl -s http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/python  | gunzip -c | grep '<updated>' | head -n1
    <updated>2017-04-04T11:18:14Z</updated>
mjpieters@mjpieters-mbp:~ $ curl -s https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/python  | gunzip -c | grep '<updated>' | head -n1
    <updated>2017-04-06T18:08:48Z</updated>
```

All addresses I connected to are reporting 04-04 except for the `https://` URL. These are CDN IP address; the 4 IP addresses I tried above are Fastly addresses:

```
$ whois 151.101.1.69 | grep Organization
Organization:   Fastly (SKYCA-3)
```

Stack Overflow uses Fastly to deliver content via local a distributed network of servers with minimal latency (you connect to a server close to you, rather than have to traverse the internet to Stack Overflow's data center).

So somewhere these servers have gotten stale, and the Python feed copy they have is no longer being updated. There are probably other feeds affected too.

Comment: The feed is still stuck somewhere. I also noticed my [Android feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/android) is doing the same thing, although from a different point in time.